# JSON deserialiser to set custom properties in POJO

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, deserialization

I'm using Jackson for json mapping on java POJOs. What I want is to set two properties in POJO from a value in JSON by splitting the value.

```
{
    "email": "xyz@hello.com",
}
```

and POJO is

```
public class TestPojo { 

    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String emailAddress; 

    /*is there any annotation available that I can split the email 
    address with a delimiter which is '@' to first and second 
    properties*/
    private String first; //gives value xyz
    private String second;//gives value hello.com
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can hijack that logic in your public setter. 
For instance:

```
class MyPojo {
        // no need for this annotation here actually, covered by setter
        // at least for deserialization
        @JsonProperty
        String email;
        String first;
        String last;

        @JsonProperty("email")
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
            String[] split = email.split("@");
            // TODO check length etc.
            this.first = split[0];
            this.last = split[1];
        }
        // just for testing
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                "email: %s, first: %s, last: %s%n", email, first, last
            );
        }
}
```

Then, somewhere else...

```
String json = "{ \"email\": \"xyz@hello.com\"}";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo pojo = om.readValue(json, MyPojo.class);
System.out.println(pojo);
```

**Output**

```
email: xyz@hello.com, first: xyz, last: hello.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using an auto-generated code with abstract methods in my base pojo. So cannot hijack setter here.

Comment: @anz then you could use a custom de-serializer, and set the `first` and `last` values there. This would require that you have setter methods for those, and of course will be a lot more tedious than just editing your pojo...

Comment: Even then, how can the deserializer will get invoked? I don't have those properties present in the json.

Comment: @anz you don't need to annotate you pojo with `@JsonDeserialize` if you can't modify it, you can register the de-serializer to your ObjectMapper. **Edit** take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) if you're looking for a decent tutorial.

Comment: I tried with ObjectMapper, but it's expecting to return the same POJO object from the deserialize method. Is there any other way by modifying at property level through deserialization?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's expecting to return the same POJO object from the deserialize method". Obviously if you're deserializing an instance of `YourPojo` the `ObjectMapper` will expect an instance of `YourPojo`. Quoting your second question: "Is there any other way by modifying at property level through deserialization?" yes as mentioned, through a custom de-serializer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183568/discussion-between-anz-and-mena).

Comment: Sorry no time for that now.